# Object integrity and caching in a stateful client

Tags: apache-flex, silverlight, caching, object

I'm wondering what strategies exist to handle object integrity in a stateful client like a Flex or Silverlight app.

What I mean is the following: consider an application where you have a Group and a Member entity. Groups contain multiple members and members can belong to multiple groups. A view lists the different groups,  which are lazy loaded (no members initially). When requesting the details of the group, all members are loaded and cached so the next time we don"t need to invoke a service to fetch the details and members of the group.

Now, when we request the details of another group that has the same member of a group that was already loaded, would we care about the fact that the member is already in memory?

If we don't, I can see a potential data conflict when we edit the member (referenced in the first group) and changes are not applied to the other member instance. So to solve this, we could check the result of the service call (that gets the group details) for members that are already loaded and then replace the loaded ones with the cached ones.

Any tips, ideas or experiences to share?

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is something that is usually solved by a "first-level cache" (in Hibernate, the "Session"; in JPA, the "EntityManager") which ensures that only one instance of a particular entity exists in a particular context. As you suggest, this could be applied to objects as they are fetched from the server to ensure that all references to a particular entity are in fact references to the same object instance.  You would also need a mechanism to ensure that entities created inside the AVM exist in that same context so they have similar logic applied to them.

The Granite Data Services project has a project called "Tide" which aims to solve this problem:

http://www.graniteds.org/confluence/display/DOC/6.+Tide+Data+Framework

As far as DDD goes, it's important not to design the backend as a simple data access API, such as simply exposing a set of DAOs or Repositories.  The client application cannot be trusted and in fact is very easy to manipulate with a debugging proxy such as Charles.  I always design a services API that is tailored to the UI (so that data for a screen can be fetched in a single call) and has necessary security or validation logic enforced, often using annotations and Spring AOP.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a client side application service which does the caching and servicing of requests for data. This would handle whether an object already exists in the cache. If you are using DDD then you'll need to decide what is going to be your aggregate root entity. Group or Member. You can't have both control each other. There needs to be one point for managing loading etc. Check out this video on DDD at the Canadian ALT.NET OpenSpaces. http://altnetpedia.com/Calgary200808.ashx